# Custom filter for events in mattermost-plugin-gitlab

Tags: gitlab, mattermost

I'm using the [mattermost-plugin-gitlab](https://github.com/mattermost/mattermost-plugin-gitlab). I know i can subscribe to labeled issues.

**But is it possible to get only messages for custom events like `issue` creation?**

E.g. i want to subscribe to messages if a new `issue` is created (and maybe closed) with a custom label like `Bug`.

But i don't want to get all other `issue` events like state changes from `ToDo` in `Doing` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
/gitlab subscriptions add someone/repox issues, label:some
```

or

```
/gitlab help
```